# checking condition(drawable == drawable)

Tags: android-widget

```
     sorry to ask question already asked. but i am helpless
   in my programi have 27 imageview's  which can display any of the 3 drawable's  i have in my drawable's folder.. and i want these imageview's  click to perform a different action for each drawable they contain..but i found that we won't be able to compare two drawable's for equality....
```

here's the code i wrote, which didn't work....

**if(((ImageView)arg0).getDrawable() != getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sq))**

i have googled it but no one was clear....they were saying we could use setTag() method but i am not able to figure out How . so please have pity on me and tell me how could i use setTag() in solving my problem with a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using setTag() is pretty straightforward. Either you use void setTag (Object tag) and you just provide an object to identify your drawable (typically a String) or if you need to store several properties you can use the void setTag (int key, Object tag) to provide an integer key.

Code example (this code has not been tested but it should explain what I mean by itself):

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

private static final String FIRST_IMAGE = "firstImage";
private static final String SECOND_IMAGE = "secondImage";

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Instantiation
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.firstimage);
imageView.setTag(FIRST_IMAGE); // The view is now tagged, we know this view embeds the first image
imageView.setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener());

ImageView anotherImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secondimgview);
anotherImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.firstimage);
anotherImageView.setTag(FIRST_IMAGE); // The view is now tagged, we know this view embeds the first image
anotherImageView.setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener());

ImageView secondImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thirdimgview);
secondImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
secondImageView.setTag(SECOND_IMAGE); // The view is now tagged, we know this view embeds the second image
secondImageView.setOnClickListener(new ImageClickListener());
}

private class ImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

// The onClick method compares the view tag to the different possibilities and execute the corresponding action.
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String tag = (String) v.getTag();
        if (v.getTag() == FIRST_IMAGE) {
            // perform specific action
        } else if (v.getTag() == SECOND_IMAGE) {

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: drawable has no setTag() method with it ...and looks like u dint ustand my question..or i dint ustand ur ans...so plz provide me a small example...wud be a gr8  help

Comment: I know that drawable have no setTag() method, I was talking of the ImageView that displays the drawable. For each ImageView, when you instantiate it, you can set its tag to identify easily the drawable it displays. Your code above would then become:

`if ((String)((ImageView)arg0).getTag() == DRAWABLE_SQ_TAG)`

Comment: moystard, many thanks for trying to answer...but i still dint get you....the part i dint get is : "when you instantiate it, you can set its tag to identify easily the drawable it displays"..HOW ?.try to elaborate it with an example...wud luv tht..

Comment: Edited my first post to provide an example

Comment: thanks a lot dude..for ur answer and patience....in fact i wasn't clear from the first post..my imageview's content(drawable) changes dynamically...it's not constant..so the pblm is finnding out wat the imageview is currently displaying...